# Why empty() method does not work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is very simple.
This is for my exercise of jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>node_jQueryAPI</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="target" id="target1">
       content1
   </div>
   <div class="target" id="target2">
       content2
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My purpose in this code is for testing about jQuery method remove() and empty();
(remove the #target1 and empty #target2)
by

```
$('#target1').remove();
$('#target2').empty();
```

This is working well in console of Chrome.

but if i use JavaScript Code like

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
targets[0].remove(); // This is working well
targets[0].empty(); // This is never working!!!! This is my Question!, Why!?!!??
```

Please Help me~!! thank you

Comment: No, there's no `empty()` method in the DOM API, why did you expect a jQuery method to work on a non-jQuery object? As for your claim that it "*never works*" I think you'll find it fits, at least, generate an error.

Comment: `.empty()` is a jQuery method on jQuery objects. `.remove()` is the name of both a jQuery method on jQuery objects and a DOM method on nodes.

Comment: You're not using jQuery in your code. Try `$(targets[0]).empty();`.

Comment: Oh Thank you,,, Is the fact that I can't mix the JavaScript and jQuery object?

Comment: @CraziliaZettoMan think of jQuery as a library built on top of Javascript that gives you additional functionality to make your life easier. If you don't use jQuery then these "convenient" functionality won't be available for you. You'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @CraziliaZettoMan Check the answer below to see how you can mimic the jQuery `empty()` method and create your own `empty()` function in JavaScript.

Comment: *"Is the fact that I can't mix the JavaScript and jQuery object?"*  Correct.  The methods that exist for a dom Element are not the same for those that exist for a jQuery object.  Just like if you created your own custom class and made methods for it, those methods would not magically be available on all other dom Elements.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to test out the jQuery methods `remove()` and `empty()` then you need to wrap the DOM element you retrieve in jQuery in order to call jQuery functions on it. Like this:

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
$(targets[0]).remove(); //will remove the first element with class `target` from the DOM
$(targets[1]).empty(); //will empty the contents of the second element with class `target` in the DOM (i.e: remove the text `content1`)
```

Please be sure to you are including the jQuery script on your page as well. Without wrapping the DOM elements in jQuery, you're calling plain javascript functions. In javascript, `remove()` exists (used to remove an option from a select list) and `empty()` does not

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted as it directly answers his question

Answer (score -2):

There is no method called `empty()` in plain JavaScript. If you want to empty an element, there are a couple of ways to do it. One of the most straight-forward approaches would be to simply assign the element's inner HTML to an empty string like this:

```js
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "";
```

```html
<p>The following div is now empty</p>
<div>ABC</div>
```

However, you can create a reusable function `empty()` that will accept an element and empty it's content like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */

function empty(x) { x.innerHTML = "" }

//You can now empty as many elements as you want using the reusable empty() function created above

var a = document.getElementById("aaa");
var b = document.getElementById("bbb");
var c = document.getElementById("ccc");

empty(a);
empty(b);
empty(c);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<p>All three divs below are now empty:</p>

<div id="aaa">ABC</div>
<div id="bbb"><p>XYZ</p></div>
<div id="ccc"><div>123</div></div>
```